# ADB Shell Input keyevent

Tags: android, adb

Hi all I want to press the 'Done' key in the android phone dial pad. is there any way we can click the  'Done' button?

I tried all the key code like: adb Shell Input keyevent 66

And all other key codes but nothing worked.

Comment: Is the enter button the same? If so try keyevent 66 looking like: `adb shell input keyevent 66`

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to find your key mappings specifically to your device:

```
adb shell cat /system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl
```

For my Pixel emulator, the key code for "**DONE**" or "**ENTER**"  is 28

```
key 28    ENTER
```

Comment: can you please share me the full keycode. like this: adb Shell Input keyevent 66

Comment: It is different per device, you need to use the command to check your specific key code

Comment: You can give it a try with 28.